# What's the best way of naming my class?

Tags: naming-conventions

I have some reports; Report1, Report2, Report3

and I'm using some Builder classes to build these reports programmatically for different scenarios and sections.

One way of naming my Grid Table builder classes is this:

```
var builder = new Report1.GridTableBuilderForSection1()
```

where Report1 is a namespace (folder).

The second approach is to use this:

```
var builder = new GridTableBuilderForReport1ForSection1()
```

in the section approach name of the classes become very long.

What's the best way to name these classes in your view?

Answer (score 0):

First of all "Section1" is a terrible choice. The above version is nicer, because you get to put things into different folders. Try be more imaginative, or whatever:

```
var bldr; (not so important)

bldr = new InitialReport.SectionHeaderBuilder()
bldr2= new InitialReport.SectionDescriptionBuilder()
```

### bldr3= new GraphSummary.SectionDataBuilder()

alternatively: (sorted the other way, I like this a lot.. but it's kinda weird depending on what your native language is)

```
b1 = new ReportInitial.getBuilderSecHeader()
b2 = new ReportSubsequent.getBuilderSecMain()
b3 = new ReportFinal.getBuilderSecGraphics()
```

.. this is great if you use auto-completion a lot.

Comment: Using my class is simpler than this; new Report1DailyBuilder().Build();

Comment: I have another class called Report1WeeklyBuilder which has also a build method.

Answer (score 0):

I've built and designed a successful high performance reporting engine for a data warehouse company a couple years ago and I used a Strategy pattern or Abstract Factory pattern to solve a similar issue...

[Strategy Pattern (wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

[Abstract Factory Pattern (wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

If you use a Strategy approach your code might look like this...

```
def report1 = new Report1()

report1.buildHeader(new FancyHeader(data);
report1.buildSection(new GridTable(data));
report1.buildFooter(new SimpleFooter(data));
```

Or if you simply looking to organize concrete classes with long names that very similar names you could use a type of static class hierarchy to make the code a little more readable...

```
def thing = Reports.GridBuilders.EmployeeGrids.DailyEmployeeAttendance
def another = Reports.GridBuilders.EmployeeGrids.WeeklyPayroll
def oneMore = Reports.GridBuilders.EmployeeGrids.Managers
```

Comment: The names I have used are like: GridTableBuilderForDepartmentReportDepartmentWeekly, GridTableBuilderForDepartmentReportDepartmentDaily, GridTableBuilderForDepartmentReportDepartment - I seek improvement to the names as they're so long.

Comment: What about a static class hierarchy for readability?  Something like... Grids.TableBuilders.DepartmentReports or Grids.TableBuilders.DepartmentReports.Daily

Comment: Do you mean that to be the name of the class or you mean the name of the class to be "Daily" inside the namespace "Grids.TableBuilders.DepartmentReports or Grids.TableBuilders.DepartmentReports"? I used GridTableBuilder.DepartmentReport.Division.Daily but it's less readable in practice in the sense that I'll have e.g. 8 classes with the same name of "Daily" so when debugging it becomes really hard to find out the current Daily class belongs to whom.

Comment: Thanks for trying my example! Each name in the chain could be a class or a package/namespace leading up to the 'Daily' class.  So you would end up with 8 classes called 'Daily' in your example.  You could add a final variable name to each class to help indicate what class it is. So, a Daily class would have a getName() which would return 'DepartmentReports.Divison.Daily'.